# How to get item count for a List's View?

Tags: list, development, list-view

I have a Sharepoint List called "Tracker" that represents customer-submitted defects.  I have a View on this list that only shows the items created in the last 7 days.  This view works just fine when I use Sharepoint using a web browser.  I want to get the count of this View using C#.

Here's the code I've attempted, but the viewCount always comes out the same as the List's item count.  What am I missing?

```
string webUrl = "https://mysharepointsite";
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(webUrl);

List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tracker");   // Should have 2107 items in it
var view = list.Views.GetByTitle("Trackers Created in Last 7 Days");  // Should have 4 items in it

context.Load(list);
context.Load(view);

context.ExecuteQuery();

int listCount = list.ItemCount;  // count = 2107

string viewQuery = view.ViewQuery;  // <Where><And><Neq><FieldRef Name="Status0" /><Value Type="Text">Closed</Value></Neq><Geq><FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value Type="DateTime"><Today OffsetDays="-7" /></Value></Geq></And></Where>

var listItemCollection = list.GetItems(new CamlQuery { ViewXml = viewQuery });            

context.Load(listItemCollection);

context.ExecuteQuery();

int viewCount = listItemCollection.Count;  // count = 2107 - this is bad, expected a value of 4
```

Comment: Are you certain your CAML is correct? What is the 'FieldRef Name="Status0"' refer to? Is this field actually called Status0? Have you tried hardcoding your ViewXml with a more strict query to be sure it works? Just a few things I have seen in the past.

Comment: The ViewQuery comes from the View (which in the Sharepoint UI returns the correct number of results) so I believe the ViewQuery CAML is correct and effective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a sample CAML query from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.getitems.aspx I noticed that their ViewXml looks different than mine.  Specifically, it's wrapped in

```
<View> and <Query>
```

tags.  Modifying the XML I get back from the View:

```
        string viewQuery = string.Format("<View><Query>{0}</Query></View>", view.ViewQuery);  // <Where><And><Neq><FieldRef Name="Status0" /><Value Type="Text">Closed</Value></Neq><Geq><FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value Type="DateTime"><Today OffsetDays="-7" /></Value></Geq></And></Where>

        var listItemCollection = list.GetItems(new CamlQuery { ViewXml = viewQuery });
```

it now works as desired.

Answer (score 1):

The count before the query will always return the amount in the list, if you perform the count after the query it will limit to the number that was returned in the results.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  How would I change the code to reflect your suggestion?

Comment: SPListItemCollection.List Gives you the parent object, you want the count of the filtered list, so I mean do the count on the list after the GetItems call. A good example of code is here in a previous question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49234/splistitemcollection-get-itemcount-with-rowlimit

Comment: the list.ItemCount property is still 2107 at the end of my code snippet though (that's what you're referring to, right?)

Comment: No, I am referring it that you are using the collection object, not the filtered list. The link I provided has the code example in the answer on how it is done.

Comment: I've looked at the link you submitted, and the question in that link is basically the same as what I'm asking - however the suggestions there say call "list.GetItems(query).Count" which is exactly what I'm doing already.  Would you be able to suggest how I could update my code to try your suggestion?

Comment: @Mike Sorry Mike, I was away. I see you have created a view for your item collection as an answer. Good work :) (I actually didn't notice ViewQuery in my rush, sorry about that)