# Programmatically add a count value to the SharePoint view

Tags: sharepoint-server, .net

I would like to add a Count = number at the top of list items in a view programmatically. I know how to do it from SharePoint, but what I want to realize is how to add this programmatically. Because we are working on site provisioning project, so it's better to be able to add this from code.[image]

Comment: have you look this post?  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51897/how-to-get-item-count-for-a-lists-view

Comment: Not yet, let me have a look cheers.